# How to update a field without authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

How to not update auditor when updating a counter?

In my DB I have a table called products and i would like to implement a visit counter. It means that anyone without authentication can visit this product. Based on this, im getting the following error because it is trying to update the Auditor (Anonyous):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to bla.bla.bla.UserEntity

Is there any annotation to tell to spring that the attribute can be updated without an authetication?

Some code:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "Products")
public class ProductEntity extends Auditable<UserEntity> {

...

@NotNull
private Long visit = 0L;

... getters and setters ...
}
```

In my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/product")
public class productController {

    @Autowired
    ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{idProduct}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView findProduct(
            @PathVariable(value="idProduct") int produtoRepository,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            Model model){


        ProductEntity p = produtoRepository.findOne(produtoRepository);

        p.setVisit(p.getVisit() + 1);
        produtoRepository.save(p);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the problem you're facing about authentication, or about casting an object ?

Comment: When i ".save", because by the auditor spring docs, they insert the user automatically based on logged user. In this situation, the is not logged user, so, the logged user is a string "anonymous"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer, i created a new table for visits, without auditor and works perfectly.